# SQL SERVER generates different and unoptimized execution plan for two similar queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

The following two queries are performed with SQL SERVER

```
SELECT TOP(10) [c].[Name] AS [I0], [c].[Surname] AS [I1],(
    SELECT MAX([r].[Date])
    FROM [Presences].[Regs] AS [r]
    WHERE ([c].[Id] = [r].[ColId]) AND [r].[ColId] IS NOT NULL) AS [I7], [c].[Id] AS [I10]
FROM [Presences].[Cols] AS [c]
```

```
SELECT TOP(10) [c].[Code] AS [I0], [c].[Description] AS [I1], (
    SELECT MAX([r].[Date])
    FROM [Presences].[Regs] AS [r]
    WHERE ([c].[Id] = [r].[CantId]) AND [r].[CantId] IS NOT NULL) AS [I9], [c].[Id] AS [I10]
FROM [Presences].[Cants] AS [c]
```

The second query is evaluated in less than 1 second but the first one takes more than 20 seconds.

Infact the generated execution plan for the first one is very different:

[Bad execution plan of the first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCujz.png)

if compared with the second one:

[Good execution plan of the second query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evFCZ.png)

It is unclear to me why an index seek is not choosen.

Those are the indexes declared on the table [Regs]:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Regs_Date] ON [Presences].[Regs]
(
    [Date] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Regs_ColId] ON [Presences].[Regs]
(
    [ColId] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Regs_CantId] ON [Presences].[Regs]
(
    [CantId] ASC
)
```

Table [Cols] has around 600 rows and table [Cants] 21000.

The interesting fact is that the following query (using FORCESEEK) generates the correct execution plan:

```
SELECT TOP(10) [c].[Name] AS [I0], [c].[Surname] AS [I1],(
    SELECT MAX([r].[Date])
    FROM [Presences].[Regs] AS [r]
    WITH (FORCESEEK)  
    WHERE ([c].[Id] = [r].[ColId]) AND [r].[ColId] IS NOT NULL) AS [I8]
FROM [Presences].[Cols] AS [c]
ORDER BY [c].[Name], [c].[Surname]
```

but I can't specify this hint because the queries are generated using an ORM.

If you need further informations I will be glad to provide them.

Comment: Can you share your plans here:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  Much of the detail is lost when you only provide a picture of the plan.

Comment: Can you share the indexes for the tables Cols and Cants as well?

Comment: This is the bad query exec plan : [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BylkjmiuL) and this is the the good one : [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJDGomjO8). The other tables have only the clustered index on the primary key (Id)

Comment: Seems like that the different execution plan is related to the number of rows in the table. The query perfoms successfully if we move from 600 Cols rows to 1000000 (unbelievable)

Comment: You have a missing index highlighted on the bad plan:  "Missing Index (Impact 99.6668): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] ON [Presences].[Regs] ([ColId]) INCLUDE ([Date])"

Comment: Your "paste the plan" links both have seeks and execute in less than half a second. Not 20 seconds

Comment: @MJH Why the index is not missing on the other query? So why should I create an index if not really required? Both the queries are similar so I was wondering why it isn't highlighted on the other one

Comment: @MartinSmith with the dataset that I've specified in the question it takes more than 20 second on the query with the Cols table but if we perform the same query against 1000000 the query executes as you say. Maybe is related to the number of rows or the size of the table?

Comment: so can you upload to paste the plan the plan that actually demonstrates the problem? with a scan

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm sorry I have uploaded the wrong plan (as you can see I have pasted the query plan with the FORCESEEK clause).  [This is the correct one](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy3CnzndI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem query is

```
SELECT TOP(10) c.Name                      AS I0,
               c.Surname                   AS I1,
               (SELECT MAX(r.Date)
                FROM   Presences.Regs AS r
                WHERE  ( c.Id = r.ColId )) AS I7,
               c.Id                        AS I10
FROM   Presences.Cols AS c 
ORDER BY c.Name, c.Surname
```

In both the good and the bad plan the top is the same

[image]

It scans the `Cols` table, sorts by `Name, Surname` and then proceeds to calculate the `MAX(Date)` in `Presences.Regs` where `r.ColId` matches the corresponding `c.Id` from the outer row.

The ideal index for this would be one on `ColId, Date` - so it can seek into the index and just read the last one for that `ColId`.

You don't have this index though so it has two choices

[image]

[image]

1. Scan `IX_Regs_Date` - this is in date order so it can stop the scan as soon as it finds the first row matching `c.Id = r.ColId`
2. Seek into `IX_Regs_ColId`. Get **all** rows matching the predicate and then aggregate them to find the `MAX`.

For option 1 it estimates that it will only have to read `283` rows per scan on average before finding the first one matching `c.Id = r.ColId`. In reality it reads `1,358,719` per execution (and there are 10 executions so this is a corresponding 13.58 million key lookups). There are `1,517,230` rows in the table so it looks as though for some reason all the ones matching the join are congregated towards later dates in the table.

The easiest way of fixing this would be to give it the ideal index of `ColId, Date` - this covers the query so removes the lookup that is present even in the "good" plan and is an obvious best choice so will remove the temptation for SQL Server to select the "bad" plan.

```
--Suggested replacement for IX_Regs_ColId
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Regs_ColId_Date] ON [Presences].[Regs]
(
    [ColId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation. I managed to create and index on Date that includes both ColId and CantId and this covers both queries following the same behavior. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @BrandoCaserotti - If the index is on `[Date] INCLUDE ([ColId], [CantId])` then this will get rid of the lookups but you still might get cases where it is scanning millions of rows from that index. The ideal index (just considering this query) is the one suggested in this answer. Each execution of the nested loops will then just need to read a single row from  `Regs`